# Comparison of Speech Recognition use in Android: by Intent or on-thread?

Tags: android, android-intent, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

## Introduction

Android provides two ways for me to use speech recognition.

The **first** way is by an `Intent`, as in this question: [Intent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335694/implementing-recognizerintent-in-android). A new `Activity` is pushed onto the top of the stack which listens to the user, hears some speech, attempts to transcribes it (normally via the cloud) then returns the result to my app, via an `onActivityResult` call.

The **second** is by getting a `SpeechRecognizer`, like the code here: [SpeechRecognizer example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559930/705048). Here, it looks like the speech is recorded and transcribed on some other thread, then callbacks bring me the results. And this is done *without leaving my `Activity`*.

I would like to understand the **pros and cons of these two ways of doing speech recognition**.

## What I've got so far

Using the `Intent`:

- is simple to code
- avoids reinventing the wheel
- gives consistent user experience of speech recognition across the device

but

- might be slow for the creation of a new activity with it's own window

Using the `SpeechRecognizer`:

- lets me retain control of UI in my app
- gives me extra possibilities of things to respond to ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html))

but

- is limited to be called from the main thread
- more control requires more error-checking.

Comment: That's odd. Why have people downvoted this question? And why not give me some feedback?

Comment: And they seem to have downvoted both answers too. Where's the love?

Comment: I think both approaches have the problem of it being slow to start. There is a delay between when the app wants speech recognition to start and when it does. At least with the Intent approach the user is aware with various dialogs, With speechrecognizer, you'd have to tell the user some other way.

Comment: Is there an alternative that isn't slow to start?

Comment: No, there is no alternative to the slow start. What's worse, is that the start time is variable. Sometimes is it fast other times slow. You have to do something with the UI to help or maybe Google will solve it by adding some helpful beeps.

Comment: Hi, can you share some example code for this? How you solve this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to all this, I'd add at least this point:

`SpeechRecognizer` is better for hands-free user interfaces, since your app actually gets to respond to error conditions like "No matches" and perhaps restart itself. When you use the `Intent`, the app beeps and shows a dialog that the user must press to continue.

My summary is as follows:

SpeechRecognizer

- Show different UI or no UI at all. Do you really want your app's UI to beep? Do you really want your UI to show a dialog when there is an error and wait for user to click?
- App can do something else while speech recognition is happening
- Can recognize speech while running in the background or from a
  service
- Can Handle errors better
- Can access low level speech stuff like the raw audio or the RMS. Analyze that audio or use the loudness to make some kind of flashing light to indicate the app is listening

Intent

- Consistent, and easy to use UI for users
- Easy to program

Comment: is one more accurate than the other? Or is the Intent version just a UI for  SpeechRecognizer?

Comment: The accuracy is the same

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is UI. `SpeechRecognizer` doesn't have any so you are responsible for creating one.
I use to wrote a prototype where I've have receiver for listening headset button, then activating speech recognition to listen for some commands. Screen was not activated so I had to use `SpeechRecognizer` (my UI was some prerecorded sounds and Text To Speech).

Second difference is that `SpeechRecognizer` has ability for constant listening. Intent version will always end exaction after some period. For example `SpeechRecognizer` is used by speech recognition "keyboard" so you can dictate a SMS.
In such case you will receive partial results only (in normal mode `SpeechRecognizer` gives only final results).

Comment: Incorrect. Both SpeechRecognizer and Intent end after a certain controllable period. With SpeechRecognizer at least you can restart it though.

Comment: You are both incorrect. ;) It all depends on the app that provides the speech recognition service. It can run as long as it wants. In case of `SpeechRecognizer` the caller can call `cancel` on it but not control the recording time. In case of the Intent the control is handed over to a new Activity which might finish only if the user presses BACK.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that the other answers have not mentioned: if multiple speech recognizers are installed on the device then user switching between them is different depending on if "Intent" or the `SpeechRecognizer` is used.

- In case of "Intent" the standard Activity selection dialog is popped up. The user can choose the recognizer to be used, and optionally set it globally as the default recognizer, to avoid the dialog in the future.
- In case of `SpeechRecognizer` the user can set and configure the default recognizer in the global settings (`Language and input -> Voice recognizer` on ICS).

So, depending on which interface is used the documentation about setting the default recognizer and switching between recognizers should be different. (In most cases though there is just one recognizer, Google Voice Search, so this might not be a big issue in practice.)